# Moving messages with VBA Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

What is the difference between these two lines?

1. `Set MyMsg = MyMsg.Move(MyFolder2)`
2. `MyMsg.Move(MyFolder2)`

The first one works just fine.
The second one usually gives an "Outlook is not responding" error.

Answer (score 1):

The MailItem.Move method returns the MailItem that has been moved. Usually, properties return values and methods don't return anything. But for several methods, the designers decided it would be handy to have a return value, so they made them return a value (or object).

When you assign a method to a variable, any arguments must be in parentheses or you'll get a syntax error. If you call a method without assigning it to a variable (because you don't care what the method returns or it's one of the methods that doesn't return a value), then the arguments must not be in parentheses (kind of).

Parentheses, when used in places that the compiler does not require them, are the equivalent of saying "evaluate this before doing anything else". It's like how you use parentheses in order of operations so you can say "evaluate this addition operation before you do this multiplication even though that's not the normal order".

The (kind of) remark above is because most of the time when you "incorrectly" put parentheses around something, it doesn't matter.

```
Application.CreateItem 0
```

and

```
Application.CreateItem (0)
```

are the same. The second one evaluates the argument before it passes it to `CreateItem`, but evaluating a single integer takes no time and has no ill effects. The parentheses aren't necessary because we're not assigning the results to a variable, but they're not really hurting anything either.

In your second example, you're telling the compiler to evaluate the folder, then send it to the Move method. I don't know what evaluating a folder means, but I gather it's not good. It probably does something like create an array of all the objects in that folder, or something equally intensive. When Outlook is not responding, it means you gave it such a big job that it hasn't checked back in with the operating system in a timely fashion.

So: Use parentheses for arguments when it's on the right side of an equal sign. Don't use them when it's not. There are a few exceptions to that rule, but you may never need to know them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two (you just ignore the function result) unless you actually use the MyMsg variable afterwards - after the message is moved, you cannot access it anymore.

Use the first version.